# How to get keys from hash - ruby c extension

Tags: ruby, ruby-c-extension

I am looking for a function which can get me all the keys from hash or I can loop through the hash to retrieve single key at a time.

Currently I am hardcoding key

```
VALUE option = rb_hash_aref(options, rb_str_new2("some_key"));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate over the key/value pairs with a callback function using [`rb_hash_foreach`](http://rxr.whitequark.org/mri/ident?i=rb_hash_foreach) ([blog post w/an example](http://clalance.blogspot.com/2011/01/writing-ruby-extensions-in-c-part-10.html)):

```
void rb_hash_foreach(VALUE, int (*)(ANYARGS), VALUE);
```

There is an [`rb_hash_keys` in MRI](http://rxr.whitequark.org/mri/source/hash.c#1647), but it's not in any header files it seems, so using it may be risky.

Comment: Yup `rb_hash_keys` complains `use of undeclared identifier 'rb_hash_keys'`

Comment: Do you have any working example? I am getting this error `candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'int (VALUE, VALUE, VALUE)' to 'int (*)(...)' for 2nd argument
void rb_hash_foreach(VALUE, int (*)(ANYARGS), VALUE);`

Comment: The MRI source has an example in `rb_hash_keys`: http://rxr.whitequark.org/mri/source/hash.c#1627

Comment: error: use of undeclared identifier 'rb_hash_keys';

Comment: Well yeah, that function contains the example.

Comment: I followed MRI source example but eventually I got the same error `candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'int (VALUE, VALUE, VALUE)' to 'int (*)(...)' for 2nd argument void rb_hash_foreach(VALUE, int (*)(ANYARGS), VALUE);`This is the code I am trying ` VALUE ary;
           ary = rb_ary_new();
           rb_hash_foreach(opts, convert_keys_to_a, ary);`  `static int
   convert_keys_to_a(VALUE key, VALUE value, VALUE ary) {
    if (logic) return ST_CONTINUE;
     if (logic {
       rb_hash_foreach(value, convert_keys_to_a, ary);
    }

       return rb_ary_push(ary, key);
    }`

Comment: What ruby version?  Compiler?  Compiler flags?  How are you building this?  Empty functions with these names compiles fine for me using [these basic instructions](http://www.rubyinside.com/how-to-create-a-ruby-extension-in-c-in-under-5-minutes-100.html).

Comment: If you are compiling for Rubinius, you may need to include the hash libraries yourself (they are not automatically included with ruby.h): `// Force inclusion of hash declarations (only MRI includes by default)
#ifdef HAVE_RUBY_ST_H
#include "ruby/st.h"
#else
#include "st.h"
#endif`

Answer (score 1):

You could always make a call to the Ruby method itself:

```
VALUE keys = rb_funcall(hash, rb_intern("keys"), 0)
```